# Наследование различных конкретных реализаций абстрактного класса

Tags: c#, объекты, наследование

Есть базовый абстрактный класс `Subj`

```
public abstract class Subj
{
    public IName name;
    public string ID { get; set; }
    //иные члены класса
}
```

От него наследуют классы `Company` и `Person` реализующие его интерфейсы:

```
public class Company : Subj
{
    //Реализует интерфейс IName
    public new  IName name = new NameCompany();
}

public class Person : Subj
{
    //Реализует интерфейс IName
    public new IName name = new NamePerson();
}
```

Есть также класс `Client`, Наследующий от `Subj`, добавляющий функционал

```
public class Client : Subj
{
    //Функционал клиента
    public string foldername()
    {
    //Возвращает имя папки
    }
    //Лист - Перечень судебных дел
    private List<LCase> _cases = new List<LCase> { };
}
```

Идея в том, что `Subj` должен быть обязательно реализован либо как `Company`, либо как `Person` и потом при необходимости расширен функционалом `Client` с сохранением публичных членов. Я знаю, множественное наследование не допускается, как лучше всего реализовать `Client` через `Company` и  `Person`?

Comment: _//Реализует интерфейс IName_ `public` **new** `IName name` - зачем вы использовали new?

Comment: @Alexander VS2019 выдал предупреждение: `"Company.name" скрывает наследуемый член "Subj.name". Если скрытие было намеренным, используйте ключевое слово new` Как я понял, на результат не влияет, но убирает предупреждение.

Comment: О том и речь, что у вас нет наследования. Следовательно, ваш вопрос не имеет смысла.

Comment: Кроме того, нужно понимать, что Name у таких разных сущностей как компания и персона не могут быть одним  и тем же Name'ом: я вот себе с трудом представляю как полное/сокращённое юридическое наименование юридического лица может быть именем человека. Тут вон у ИП/ЮЛ есть куча отличий, но там хотя бы действительно общий предок может пригодиться, но с человеком... нет, не очень удачны дизайн классов, потом с очень высокой степенью вероятности придётся переделывать.

Comment: 1) `реализующие его интерфейсы` - у вас тут нет интерфейсов 2) `public new  IName name` - если вам надо что то переопределять, используйте virtual + override, `new` не является переопределением. 3) `public IName name;` не используйте поля в базовых классах, используйте свойства, так у вас будет больше контроля.

Comment: все ваши попытки с ООП разобьются кодом `var company = new Conpany(); company.name = new NamePerson();` - на этом простом примере вы можете видеть, что ваша архитектура вам никак не помогает.